# Returning Data from Firestore giving error

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

OK I have an error I am getting trying to return the data from a collection in Firestore.

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

The error is pointing to the .get() here

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.noteService
    .getNoteList()
    .get()
    .then(noteListSnapshot => {
      this.noteList = [];
      noteListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.noteList.push({
          id: snap.id,
          noteBottle: snap.data().noteBottle,
          noteDistillery: snap.data().noteDistillery,
          noteDate: snap.data().noteDate,
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
}
```

I think the issue is really in my service though which looks like this...

```
public noteListRef: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
public currentUser: firebase.User;

constructor() {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
      this.noteListRef = firebase.firestore().collection(`/userProfile/${this.currentUser.uid}/eventList`);
    }
  });
}
```

Any ideas to why get is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to resolve the user promise before you try to use it with other stuff.

This repo shows how to do it without these errors:

https://github.com/javebratt/ionic-angular-firebase-authentication-starter/blob/master/src/app/services/auth.service.ts

https://github.com/javebratt/ionic-angular-firebase-authentication-starter/blob/master/src/app/services/profile.service.ts

You get your user using something like this:

```
  getUser(): Promise<firebase.User> {
    return this.afAuth.authState.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  }
```

Which means you can then use it like this:

```
  async getUserProfile(): Promise<Observable<UserProfile>> {
    const user: firebase.User = await this.authService.getUser();
    this.currentUser = user;
    this.userProfile = this.firestore.doc(`userProfile/${user.uid}`);
    return this.userProfile.valueChanges();
  }
```